# Using composer for a specific project

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been trying to install and use composer for a "php sql parser" code (available [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-sql-parser/)).

I've installed composer with the windows package. However, ater reading 3 tutorials, I'm not sure on what to do next. I think I should create a .json file somewhere and use command line after that. But nothing more precise.

Comment: Where have you got to? What code have you tried? This is far too vague.

Comment: Sorry but I cant be more precise. I've installed Composer through the windows installer. I just dont know what the next step should be. Documentation (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) says I have to create a json file in the vendor folder with name of required dependencies and import dependencies with a terminal commande line. However I dont know what dependencies are required for the php-sql-parser. Well I'm lost in the process...

Comment: I solved this - I'm not sure why but the process had nothing to do with documentation. Composer.json is located at the root of the projet directory. You have to go to this folder with the terminal and type "composer install". Next step is to include the autoload.php in the project (created by composer in the vendor folder)